# using else if in a function in R

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I 'm trying to use else if within a function in R

```
new<-function(a,b,c,d){
if (a==1){
var1<-100+100+100
var2<-500+500+500
var3<-500-100

}else if (a==2){
var1<-100+100
var2<-500+500
var3<-500-10
} else if (a==3){
var1<-100
var2<-500
var3<-500
}

b<-var1-var2

c<- var2+var3

d<-var3-var1

if (b<100)
{print ("the value is good")
}else if (b>100)
{ print("check teh value")
}else 
{print ("repeat")
}
}

output<-new(3,b,c,d)
```

I feel something fundamental is wrong with this which I m missing. I 'm trying to use else if to populate the values to be used as an input to call the same fucntion.

Help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What you are returning from your function? (only the value of the last evaluated expression, because you not have a explicit `return(...)`)

Comment: What is your expected outcome?  a == 3, so we end up with var1<-100, var2<-500, and var3<-500. Hence _b = -400_, _c = 1000_, _d = 400_. So _if (b<100)_  is satisfied and you _print ("the value is good")_

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify to:

```
new <- function(a) {
  if (a == 1) {
    b <- -1200
  } else if (a == 2) {
    b <- -800
  } else if (a == 3) {
    b <- -400
  }
  
  if (b < 100)
  {
    print ("the value is good")
  } else if (b > 100)
  {
    print("check the value")
  } else
  {
    print ("repeat")
  }
  return(b) # for fun return the value of b
}

output <- new(2)
```

But this function will always have the side effect of printing "the value is good" because b always evaluates to a negative number. What's the purpose?
If you would want to return values a to d, you could do the intermediate calculations as per your example and do: `return(list(a = a, b = b, c = c, d = d))` instead of `return(b)`.